# Repeat label along line in MapServer

Tags: labeling, mapserver

I'm new in MapServer and want to create a labeling for line geometry.
The label should be repeated multiple times alone the line geometry. I tried the command `REPEATDISTANCE`, but it doesn't work as I imagined.

```
LABEL
            TEXT "This layer does not currently contain any data. If you have any questions, please contact:"
            BUFFER 5
            OUTLINEWIDTH 1
            COLOR 0 0 0 
            FONT sans-bold
            TYPE TRUETYPE
            SIZE 6
            ANTIALIAS true
            MINFEATURESIZE 1
            REPEATDISTANCE 2
            POSITION uc
            ANGLE FOLLOW
            OFFSET 3 3
            PARTIALS false
            STYLE
                GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly'    
                COLOR 255 255 255
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0  
                WIDTH 0.5
            END 
        END
```

I get only one label, but I want the labeling to be repeated over and over again.

Comment: Change "partials" into "true" as a test. Your text is long, with repeatdistance of 2 pixels there is probably no room for new  and not overlapping labels.

Comment: Did you make the test with partials-true?